# Python: Function name not defined

Tags: python, python-2.7

Basically, I'm working on an AI project and I am trying to make a loop that does it as long as one coordinate is <= to another coordinate and I have defined a function but when I try to call it it has this error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "not important", line 66, in
>
> A()
>
> NameError: name 'A' is not defined

and if I try to re-arrange the definition it runs into a variable problem fixed by being placed where it is.

Here is my code (Note I am using pygame for the actual Interface)

```
import pygame as pg
import math
import time
import random


#starts pygame/create window
pg.init()
screen = pg.display.set_mode((800,600))
pg.display.set_caption("AI ALG")
clock = pg.time.Clock()

#Presets
KillerX = 50
KillerY = 50
EnemyX = 375
EnemyY = 275
gray = (255,255,255)
font = pg.font.Font(None, 32)
TICKSPASSED = 0
font_color = (100, 200, 150)
killertexture = pg.Surface((25,25))
killertexture.fill((0, 255, 0))
enemytexture = pg.Surface((25,25))
enemytexture.fill((255, 0, 0))
startAI = False





#main loop
runing = True
while runing:



    ticktxt = font.render(str(TICKSPASSED), True, font_color)
    activetxt = font.render(str(startAI), True, font_color)
    COO1 = font.render(str(KillerX), True, font_color)
    clock.tick(60)
    keys = pg.key.get_pressed()
    #events
    if keys[pg.K_SPACE]:
        startAI = True
        TICKSPASSED += 1
        


    for event in pg.event.get():

        #if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            #runing = False

        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            runing = False

    #update
    #render
    screen.fill(gray)
    screen.blit(ticktxt, ((8,8), (8,8)))
    screen.blit(activetxt, ((730,8), (792,8)))
    screen.blit(COO1, ((730,8), (792,8)))
    screen.blit(killertexture, (KillerX,KillerY))
    screen.blit(enemytexture, (EnemyX,EnemyY))
    A()
    pg.display.flip()


def A():
    if not KillerX <= EnemyX:
        KillerX =- .5

pg.quit()
```

Any help would be awesome, thanks

also sorry if my code is messy :)

Answer (score 0):

You should define `A` before it is referenced. Move the definition of `A` before the `while` loop, in which `A` is called, and the error would go away.

Note that you should also either declare `KillerX` and `EnemyX` as global variables in the function `A`, or make them parameters to `A` and make `A` return the altered `KillerX`.

Answer (score 0):

The code you're running is in-line, rather than in a function, so it is run as soon as it's encountered in the file, which is before it has seen the definition of function `A`.  You can move the definition of `A` up to a point before it's referenced, or you can place your main code in a function that you call at the end of the file.  The definition of `A` just needs to be seen before you attempt to call it.